# SQL Server Java driver not working in class path

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

I have written a simple Java file to handle some SQL that is integrated with SQL server.

I downloaded the appropriate driver and stored the JAR in the correct class path however it only works if I run the file directly.

I have tried calling methods within the sql class from another class and i get the following error:

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver

I understand that this issue is well documented but it doesn't address my unique problem which is that it works within the file but not externally.

Another issue is that after the program is closed and rebuild my program forgets that the JAR was added as a library and requires me to add it again which is not good.

I have tried adding the class path by manually copying and pasting it into an XML config file but this is a hacky solution and I would rather do it properly. Please let me know where I am going wrong.

```
    <CLASSES>
       <root url="jar://$USER_HOME$/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.ow2.asm/asm/5.0.4/da08b8cce7bbf903602a25a3a163ae252435795/asm-5.0.4.jar!/" />
       <root url="jar://$USER_HOME$/IdeaProjects/r3prototypingCFS/contracts/src/main/kotlin/com/r3corda/protocols/sqljdbc42.jar!/" />
    </CLASSES>
```

```
Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
```

Comment: which IDE do you use? and how do you do to set your jar to classpath?

Comment: If you get a `ClassNotFoundException`, then you either don't have it on the classpath, or you are using the wrong class name.

Comment: So essentially what you're trying to describe is that everything works fine when running the program directly from an IDE, but as soon as you build it into a jar you get the classpath exception. Right?

Answer (score 0):

Use jdts driver ..it work with Sql Server 2014.

pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sourceforge.jtds/jtds -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sourceforge.jtds</groupId>
        <artifactId>jtds</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

and src

```
import java.sql.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
    // write your code here
        Connection conn = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        String url = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost:1433/DATABASENAME";
        String driver = "net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver";
        String userName = "username";
        String password = "yourpassword";
        try {
            Class.forName(driver);
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, userName, password);
            System.out.println("Connected to the database!!! Getting table list...");
            Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();

            String sql = "SELECT top 10 PhoneNumber,RegistrationDate\n" +
                    "      \n" +
                    "  FROM tblProductRegistration";
           // ResultSet resultSet = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

          //  String selectSQL = "SELECT USER_ID, USERNAME FROM DBUSER WHERE USER_ID = ?";
            //Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
            ResultSet resultSet = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
           // preparedStatement.setInt(1, 1001);
           // ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery( );
            //STEP 5: Extract data from result set
            while(resultSet.next()){
                //Retrieve by column name
                String PhoneNumber  = resultSet.getString("PhoneNumber");
                String RegistrationDate  = resultSet.getString("RegistrationDate");


                //Display values
                System.out.print("PhoneNumber: " + PhoneNumber);
                System.out.print("RegistrationDate: " + RegistrationDate);

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            conn.close();
            rs.close();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I can't honestly believe changing to use jTDS would make the slightest difference.  The questioner is struggling to get a JAR file to be recognised.  All your proposed solution is likely to achieve is a change in the name of the class that he cannot load.

Comment: Sorry ...but i have also tried with jdbc driver with sql server and failed most of the time ..then move myself to jTds...its cool and cooler than jdc for Sql server ..